# Is it possible to plot rational functions in R?

Tags: r, function, math, plot

Is it possible to plot rational functions in R? For example:

[image]

`curve(((x+2)*(x-5))/((x-3)*(x+1)), from=-8,to=9)` gives plots that are incorrect
probably because the function cannot be deinfed at x=-1 and x=4

Thanks a lot

Comment: You really need to add the actual R-code you tried.

Comment: it's a bit cheesy, but for any integer value of `num` this should work: `num <- 100; curve(((x+2)*(x-5))/((x-3)*(x+1)), from=-8,to=9,n=num*17+1,ylim=c(-20,20))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R seems to handle even the asymptotic explosions fairly gracefully:

```
curve( (x-5)*(x-3)/( (x+1)*(x-4) ), 3 ,5)
```

To handle the case of discontinuity, increase `n` and replace 'y' with NA above a threshold.

```
vals <- curve( (x-5)*(x-3)/( (x+1)*(x-4) ), -3 ,5, n=1000)
is.na(vals$y) <- abs(vals$y) > 100
plot(vals, type="l")
```

Comment: Not exactly. Check: curve( (x-5)*(x-3)/( (x+1)*(x-4) ), -3 ,5)

Comment: Well, the other test I gave it was from -10 to 10 and it did leave an appropriate gap at 4 in that case. You can also add an `n` parameter for increased resolution, and if you want we can show you how to insert NA's that would break at the asymptotes.

Comment: Nice trick. Unless any other answer come up, this will do. Thanks again